# Azure: Waiting Dataset dependencies in manual created pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've created a few simple pipelines in data factory with different kinds of linked services and datasets. Manually, by writting jsons. But none works.

Pipeline created by wizard works and have Ready status. All manual pipelines have status Waiting: Dataset dependencies.
What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: the key point was to add to input dataset the "external = true" property because WebLinkedService is used so this source is so called "external" in relation to Azure

Answer (score 11):

Also, need to set external property of upstream dataset to true

```
    "external": true,
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution/#modeling-datasets-with-different-frequencies):

> Some scenarios require the ability to produce output at a frequency
>   different than frequencies of one or more inputs. Data factory
>   supports modeling these scenarios.
>
> . . .
>
> The output slice for every day depends on 24 hourly slices from input
>   dataset. Data factory computes these dependencies automatically by
>   figuring out the input data slices that fall in the same time period
>   as the output slice to be produced. **If any of the .. input slices is
>   not available** (due to processing happening in an activity upstream
>   that produces the that slice for example) **data factory will wait for
>   the input slice to be ready before kicking off the daily activity
>   run.**

So you're doing something where your input data slices aren't available to the data factory. Unfortunately, without you posting your pipeline JSON, it's hard to diagnose the issue.